# Как изменить ссылки только некоторых слов из сообщения и получить его от бота с изменëнными ссылками в aiogram 3

Tags: python, aiogram-3.x

Допусти я отправляю боту текст с двумя словами с ссылками:"привет **[друг](https://m.vk.com/feed)**, можешь заглянуть на этот **[сайт](https://m.youtube.com/)**" А бот в ответ должен присылать мне тот же текст но в словах с ссылками он должен поменять эти ссылки на другие, допустим слово друг ведь на профиль в [вк](https://m.vk.com/feed) а слово [сайт](https://m.youtube.com/) на YouTube, а в изменëнном ботм сообщение слово [друг](https://web.telegram.org/a/) будет вести на профиль в тг а слово [сайт](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) на stack overflow, или хотя бы оба слова должны вести на профиль в тг, то есть к обоим словам дрбавить одну и ту же сылку, как можно этого добится.
Я пробовал сделать так:

```
Async def chang_hrefs(message:Message):
    For entity in message.entities:
        If entity.url != None:
            entity.url = "новая ссылка"
    message.answer(message.text)
```

Но в таком случае я получаю обычный текст вообще без ссылок как это можно исправить?